# Openshift RBAC policy to allow projects in preview environment to access images from different project

Tags: openshift, okd, jenkins-x

I am using OKD with Jenkinsx setup and jenkinsx creates a project dynamically based on a Pull Request created by a developer and deploys the services in that project.

But the services in those projects fails with "ImagePullBackOff" error since the pods in those projects are unable to access images from a different project.

I am trying to allow the projects under preview environment to access images from a different project.

Since the projects under preview environment are dynamically generated, I can add the image puller policy after the project has been created.

```
oc policy add-role-to-user system:image-puller system:serviceaccount:<project-b>:default --namespace=<project-a>
```

But I need a policy/command to allow pods in projects under preview environment to access images from a different project before the projects got created.

Please let me know the polcy/process to do it. Any suggestions here would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to give a RoleBinding to the group and project you want to deploy. 
There is sample how to give RoleBinding to specific group on specific Project: 
[project-rolebinding-give-authority-to-project-specific-](https://github.com/fahmifahim/openshift/blob/master/01.openshift-cheatsheet.md#user-group-project-rolebinding-give-authority-to-project-specific-)